# Updating Prior with data in python - Beta and Normal Distribution

Tags: python, probability, bayesian

I have a beta distribution parameterised by **alpha = 40**, **beta = 100**. I have data collected, and I want to update the prior with this data.

Apologies in advance, I think I am having a brain freeze today!

I think the answer is to use MCMC, but I am not entirely sure. I feel like the system is simple, we know that the posterior is proportional to the likelihood times the prior.

Using something like:

```
rh_real_dt = np.abs(np.random.randn(20))
with pm.Model() as model:

alpha = pm.Normal('alpha',mu = 40, sigma =1 )
beta = pm.Normal('beta',mu = 100,sigma =1)

RH_real = pm.Beta('RH_real',alpha = alpha,beta = beta,observed = rh_real_dt)
#step =pm.NUTS() #sets type of model
#start= pm.find_MAP()

# draw 5000 posterior samples
trace = pm.sample(5000, init='advi+adapt_diag_grad')
```

But given data points, how does that translate to likelihood?

I have used normal distributions to describe the prior of the alpha,beta parameters for beta distribution. Is this how I should be thinking about this?

Secondly, the approach used above gives me the error of 'bad energy'. 
When I use `model.check_test_point()`, I get the answer:

`alpha     -0.92
beta      -0.92
RH_real    -inf`

Any thoughts if:

1. I'm utilising the correct method to get the answer
2. Why I am getting the error and how I might be able to alleviate it?

Comment: The beta distribution is supposed to represent a variable, exactly, a value between 0 and 1. So I want to take the prior distribution and update it with the data (likelihood) to it, to get a posterior.

Comment: It likely fails because the observed data `rh_real_dt` is sampled from a Half-Gaussian, which ranges outside the domain of the Beta distribution. Why not use Beta observations? E.g., `rh_real_dt = np.random.beta(a=50, b=50, size=20)`. As for priors, normals again don't make sense because they violate the range. Usually people do a reparameterization so that instead of `a` and `b` they use a mean plus some form of scale variable (e.g., sd), otherwise the parameters are highly correlated. Model questions, however, are better posed to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).